# not able to select all records for a particular id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in SQL as given below: I need to select all records for a particular user_id:

```
mysql> select * from matusermeta limit 10;
```

```
+----------+---------+----------------------+---------------------------------+
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key             | meta_value                      |
+----------+---------+----------------------+---------------------------------+
|        1 |       1 | first_name           | sandeep                         |
|        2 |       1 | last_name            | kumar                           |
|        3 |       1 | nickname             | sk4222                          |
|        4 |       1 | description          |                                 |
|        5 |       1 | rich_editing         | true                            |
|        6 |       1 | comment_shortcuts    | false                           |
|        7 |       1 | admin_color          | fresh                           |
|        8 |       1 | use_ssl              | 0                               |
|        9 |       1 | show_admin_bar_front | true                            |
|       10 |       1 | matcapabilities      | a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} |
+----------+---------+----------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I am using this query "select * from wp_usermeta group by user_id"

```
      


+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key   | meta_value |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
|        1 |       1 | first_name | sandeep    |
|       58 |       4 | first_name | test       |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

not all the records are showing for a particular id

Comment: Use WHERE clause, not GROUP BY clause. SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE  user_id = 1

Comment: this is default behavior of group by! will group records.

Comment: ok,but i want select all records for all user_ids ,for example user_id can be 1,2,3

Comment: SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 );

Comment: @user3051901 : use the **WHERE** clause with **IN** clause also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select record of all userid in you table use:

```
SELECT * FROM [wp_usermeta] WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM [wp_usermeta])
```

If you want to get record of specific userid use:

```
SELECT * FROM [wp_usermeta] WHERE user_id IN ('1','2','95','1204')
```

Answer (score 0):

you are grouping by user_id not selecting, if you want select all records for a particular user_id, try this:

```
select * from wp_usermeta where user_id=your_particular_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from wp_usermeta where user_id = Your_ID
```

You can the use the above code to fetch data for a Particular UserID

```
select * from wp_usermeta where user_id IN ( Your_ID1, Your_ID2, Your_ID3)
```

You can the use the above code to fetch data for any number of  UserID